# demo-persistence as scp-cf-spring based on current sdk version

Tags: s4sdk

I was looking at the demo-persistence example [here at github](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/tree/master/Demo-Persistence).

Is this example / or a similar one available based on a current s4sdk version 2.x.x with spring 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a similar example is available in the branch [15_2_spring_boot](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-book/tree/15_2_spring_boot) of the [example repository](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-book) for the book *Extending SAP S/4HANA*. It is using version 2.8.0 of the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK and Spring Boot 2.0.6.